# Firebase Pricing for Remote config/FCM/Analytics

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

This really might be a dumb question around firebase. With free tier, we have a quota of limited reads and writes.

1. Does this read/write limit exist only for Databases (`Realtime/Firestore`)?
2. Does reads also count towards read calls to remote config? `Remote config` is documented as free, so what is free exactly? We have unlimited number of key-value or also their reads.
3. Similar question for analytics, if I start to log data from my application, then is writes are calculated towards my free tier?
4. Same repeated question for Cloud Messaging. Will I be charged for running cloud functions to invoke push notifications but no cost for actual push notifications?

Comment: Answers for #1, #2 and #4 are below. I recommend posting a separate question for Analytics (#3), as the answer there is different.

Comment: Question for Analytics:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76418175/firebase-pricing-for-analytics

Answer (score 1):

All Firebase quota, pricing and limits are per product.

---

Firebase Remote Config is free to use. The only limits on usage are those mentioned in the documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/remote-config#policies_and_limits).

Firebase Cloud Message is free to use. Its limits too are mentioned in the documentation, and are mostly around [message size](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#notifications_and_data_messages) and around [throttling and scaling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#throttling-and-scaling) (as those may affect service availability).

Neither of these products has a quote beyond which you are expected to pay.

---

For the Firebase Realtime Database and Cloud Firestore each project has a free quota that is documented on the [Firebase pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing).

If your project is on the free plan, the service stops working when you reach that free quota.

If your project is on the paid plan, you will start paying once your usage surpasses the free quota.

Comment: Thanks. So products FCM, Remote Config and DB quota do not interfere with each other. And free to use for a product means, any number if reads/invokes for that product. Is it right statement?

Comment: The products are free to use, and don't impose quote based restrictions on usage that can be removed by paying. If there were, the pricing page I linked would show that - or link to a page that shows it.

Comment: [Here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing), its says "No costs" and didn't mentioned about the restrictions. Is you answer still valid for today @FrankvanPuffelen ?